# How do I change behaviour for ons-splitter-side to push ons-splitter-content to the side, instead of the current "go on top" to reveal?

Tags: javascript, mobile, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

How do I change behaviour for ons-splitter-side to push ons-splitter-content to the side, instead of the current "go on top" to reveal?

To see a working example of what I have now, [click to see example here](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons-splitter-side.html#tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<ons-sliding-menu>` element instead. For more information check the documentation: https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-sliding-menu.html